# Bottom navigation bar only appears after hot restart?

Tags: flutter, dart

After pressing the elevated button, I'm navigated to HomeScreen2 but my bottom navigation bar doesn't show.

It used to show a left chevron arrow/back button that navigated back to the page with the elevated button(profile set up). And then on that page it had another back button, which took me to HomeScreen2 and it had the bottom navigation bar. I was able to get rid off the back button with Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil but after changing that I still don't have the bottom navigation bar. Unless I press hot restart..

```
ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                final username = _usernameController.text.trim();
                final name = _nameController.text.trim();

                final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
                if (user != null) {
                  try {
                 
                    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                        .collection('users')
                        .doc(user.uid)
                        .update({
                      'username': username,
                      'name': name,
                    });

                    final profilePictureURL =
                        await loadProfilePicture(user.uid);
                    await loadProfilePicture(user.uid);

                    Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreen2()),
                      (route) => false,
                    );
                  } catch (e) {
                    // Handle errors
                    print(e);
                    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                      SnackBar(
                        content: Text('Error saving profile details.'),
                      ),
                    );
                  }
                }
              },
              child: const Text('Save Profile'),
            ),
```

Here is my navigation bar:

```
class Navigation extends StatefulWidget {
 final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

  Navigation({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _NavigationState createState() => _NavigationState();
}

class _NavigationState extends State<Navigation> {
  int _selectedIndex = 2;

  List<Widget> getWidgetOptions() {
    // Initialize _widgetOptions inside the build method
    return [
      Test(note: NoteModel()),
      Options(bookmarkedRecipes: [],),
      HomeScreen2(),
      Test(note: NoteModel()),
      Profile(users: UserModel()),
    ];
  }

  void _onItemTap(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _widgetOptions = getWidgetOptions(); // Retrieve _widgetOptions from a method

    return Scaffold(
      extendBody: true,
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      body: Stack(
        children: [_widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex)],
      ),

      bottomNavigationBar: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          color: Color(0xFF162242),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
            topRight: Radius.circular(30.0),
          ),
        ),
        child: Theme(
          data: ThemeData(
            splashColor: Colors.transparent,
            highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
          ),
          child: BottomNavigationBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            showUnselectedLabels: false,
            showSelectedLabels: false,
            type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
            elevation: 0,
            items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(MyFlutterAppHouse.sketch_house, size: 27.5),
                label: '',
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(MyFlutterAppOptionsLong.sketch_options_long, size: 35),
                label: '',
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(MyFlutterAppBook.sketch_book, size: 34),
                label: '',
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(MyFlutterAppSearch.sketch_search, size: 34),
                label: '',
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(MyFlutterAppPerson.sketch_person, size: 30.5),
                label: '',
              ),
            ],
            currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
            onTap: _onItemTap,
            unselectedItemColor: const Color(0xFF677CA7),
            selectedItemColor: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I don't see what the problem is. Please help me out. If you think the problem is else where let me know

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but  `Navigator.pop(context);` worked